# Why does the Jacobian have constant sign for connected sets?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, jacobian

Why does the Jacobian have constant sign for connected sets?

I've seen in two separate proofs now (having to do with manifold orientation) that the Jacobian has constant sign for a connected set, but I can't seem to figure out why that's the case.

One of the proofs I am trying to follow goes like this (From Munkres *Analysis on Manifolds*):

"We must show $M$ may be covered by such coordinate patches. Given $p \in M$, let $\alpha: U \rightarrow V$ be a coordinate patch about p. Now $U$ is open in either $\mathbb{R}^n$ or $\mathbb{H}^n$; by shrinking $U$ if necessary, we can assume that $U$ is either an open $\epsilon$-ball or the intersection with $\mathbb{H}^n$ of an open $\epsilon$-ball. **In either case, $U$ is connected, so $\det{D\alpha}$ is either positive or negative on all of $U$...**"

Here $M$ is an n-dimensional manifold in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\alpha: U \rightarrow V$ is a diffeomorphism.

There is more after this, but the only part I do not understand is the part bolded.

Comment: It is easier to tell us which parts of the two proof you do not understand.

Comment: @ArcticChar Updated! Does that help?

Comment: looks like the idea is that $D\alpha$ can not be zero inside of $U$ since $U$ is connected and $\alpha$ is injective

Comment: Is the map a local diffeomorphism, per chance?

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes, it is! I will edit that in my question.

Comment: This means the determinant is nowhere zero ....

Comment: @TedShifrin This makes sense, but how can you then claim that the determinant has the same sign everywhere on the set?

Comment: Once you have a point where the determinant is non-zero, by continuity you can choose a smaller neighbourhood contains that point where the determinant is non-zero there.

Comment: Intermediate value theorem!!